# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate, curl_errno 60

Tags: rest-api, integration, security, php, oauth

I'm trying to integrate PHP script with Salesforce by following the example on the link:
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

But I get the error message at demo_rest.php page which says:
Error: call to URL https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/ failed with status 0, response , curl_error SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate, curl_errno 60

I already configured the cacert.pem in php.ini file(WAMP Server)

Comment: Were you trying to use curl with `-k` option to figure out if it does not verify the certificate? Which php.ini file are you modyfing? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60

Answer (score 2):

Just insert some piece of code under the demo_rest.php Line no 11 below

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false)
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)